# Laravel 5.6 multi auth keeps on authenticating on default model

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.6

I have a two table login: examinee and company. company is my default auth,
every time i try to attempt auth in examinee it keeps on using the default table which is the company.

I've seen several problems that are similar to mine but it doesn't seem to work for me or I might have overlooked something that maybe some of you might be able to see.

What am I doing wrong?

Auth.php:

```
'defaults' => [
    'guard' => 'web',
    'passwords' => 'companies',
],

'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'companies',
    ],
    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'token',
        'provider' => 'companies',
    ],
    'examinees' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'examinees',
    ],
],

'providers' => [
    'companies' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\Company::class,
    ],
    'examinees' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\Examinee::class,
    ],
],

'passwords' => [
    'companies' => [
        'provider' => 'companies',
        'table' => 'password_resets',
        'expire' => 60,
    ],
    'examinees' => [
        'provider' => 'examinees',
        'table' => 'password_resets',
        'expire' => 60,
    ],
],
```

LoginController:

```
public function showLoginForm()
{
    return view('examinee.auth.login');
}

protected function guard()
{
    return Auth::guard('examinees');
}

public function login(Request $request) {
    $user = Examinee::where('email', $request->get('email'))->first();

    if (Auth::attempt(['id' => $user->id, 'password' => $request->get('password')])) {

        // prints data from Company table instead of Examinee...
        echo "AUTH USER:<pre>";
        print_r(Auth::user());
        echo "</pre>";
        // return redirect('/home');
    }
}
```

Model:

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class Examinee extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    protected $table = 'examinees';
    protected $fillable = ['email',  'password'];
    protected $hidden = ['password',  'remember_token'];

    public $timestamps = false;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

How ive done this in the past is to add the guard to your auth

Change 
`Auth::attempt(['id' => $user->id, 'password' => $request->get('password')`

to 
`Auth::guard('examinees')->attempt(['id' => $user->id, 'password' => $request->get('password')`

Comment: I just realized i've tried this before and i got confused because it says i'm logged in but Auth::user() isn't showing anything. Turns out i have to use Auth::guard('examinees')->user() to get the auth data. But does that mean i have to add the guard everytime?